# VBA code to group and index

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a function of a spreadsheet that will group rows based on a column, and then count the number in each group while also categorizing the group.

I have a list of names and family status such as this:

```
Bob     Employee    
Laura   Spouse    
Steve   Child    
Jim     Employee    
Brian   Employee    
Amy     Spouse    
Jon     Employee    
Kelly   Child
```

And I want it to be grouped by employee with a list of dependents and a tiering system.. to look like this

```
Name     # Dependents    Tier    
Bob           2         EE+Family    
Jim           0         EE    
Brian         1         EE+Spouse    
Jon           1         EE+Child
```

I had been trying to take a nested if approach

```
For i=1 to NumberOfRows

  If status(i) = spouse

    go up 1 row increment dependent count & add EE+Spouse, delete row

  Else if status(i) = kid

    go up 1 row increment dependent & add EE+child
```

But this was only working when there was only a child or spouse.. not both.
Also forgot to mention the lists will always be ordered with employee first followed by dependents.  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you need more `if` statements.

Comment: Or look into [`Select Case`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/case.php) as an `If` alternative

Comment: I think you would be better served by adding a column that tracks Employee for all rows. So for each spouse and child row it would indicate the Employee. Much like a Foreign Key referencing the same table. This would make much easier to generate reports for this.

Comment: Loop backwards with two booleans that reset to false every time it finds "Employee" and deleting as it goes.  When it find "Employee" then it check those booleans and makes the determination of which of the four teirs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting the "Tier" to a numerical value, you can change it to text later on. That way, you would get something like this:

```
Sub dadada()
  Dim data As Variant, output() As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, mb As VbMsgBoxResult
  With Sheets("sheet1")
    data = .[A1].Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 2).Value2
    ReDim output(1 To UBound(data), 1 To 3)
    output(1, 1) = "Name"
    output(1, 2) = "# Dependents"
    output(1, 3) = "Tier"
    j = 1
    For i = 1 To UBound(data)
      If data(i, 2) = "Employee" Then
        j = j + 1
        output(j, 1) = data(i, 1)
        output(j, 2) = 0
        output(j, 3) = 0
      ElseIf data(i, 2) = "Spouse" Then
        output(j, 2) = output(j, 2) + 1
        output(j, 3) = output(j, 3) Or 1
      ElseIf data(i, 2) = "Child" Then
        output(j, 2) = output(j, 2) + 1
        output(j, 3) = output(j, 3) Or 2
      ElseIf Len(data(i, 2)) Then '<- skip start
        mb = MsgBox("Can't evaluate '" & data(i, 2) & "' at row " & i & " ('" & data(i, 1) & "')!", vbAbortRetryIgnore + vbApplicationModal + vbCritical, "Error")
        If mb = vbAbort Then Exit Sub
        If mb = vbRetry Then
          If MsgBox("Is this a new employee?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            data(i, 2) = "Employee"
          ElseIf MsgBox("Is this a new spose?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            data(i, 2) = "Spouse"
          Else
            MsgBox "'" & data(i, 2) & "' will be used as 'Child'."
            data(i, 2) = "Child"
          End If
          i = i - 1
        End If '<- skip end
      End If
    Next
    For i = 2 To j
      output(i, 3) = "EE" & Application.Choose(output(i, 3) + 1, "", "+Spouse", "+Child", "+Family")
    Next
    .[E1].Resize(i - 1, 3).Value = output
  End With
End Sub
```

the `mb` part is optional (so if you do not like it, simply delete all lines between and including `skip start` and `skip end`)

Answer (score 1):

I decided to use arrays to speed it up a little.

This will also put the Data in E1, which can be changed.

This loops backwards keeping counts until it find "Employee"

```
Sub foo()
Dim inarr() As Variant
Dim oarr() As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cnt As Long
Dim spouse As Integer
Dim child As Integer


Set ws = ActiveSheet

With ws
    inarr = .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value
    cnt = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("B:B"), "Employee")
    ReDim oarr(1 To cnt, 1 To 3)
End With
cnt = 1
For i = UBound(inarr, 1) To 1 Step -1
    Select Case inarr(i, 2)
        Case "Spouse"
            spouse = spouse + 1
        Case "Child"
            child = child + 1
        Case "Employee"
            oarr(cnt, 1) = inarr(i, 1)
            oarr(cnt, 2) = spouse + child
            If spouse > 0 And child > 0 Then
                oarr(cnt, 3) = "EE+family"
            ElseIf spouse > 0 And child = 0 Then
                oarr(cnt, 3) = "EE+Spouse"
            ElseIf spouse = 0 And child > 0 Then
                oarr(cnt, 3) = "EE+Child"
            Else
                oarr(cnt, 3) = "EE"
            End If
            spouse = 0
            child = 0
            cnt = cnt + 1
    End Select
Next i
ws.Range("E1").Resize(UBound(oarr, 1), 3).Value = oarr

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton -- this is almost exactly what I ended up using, logic wise.  Going backwards with the counters really makes it a lot easier.

Comment: Please consider marking correct by clicking the check mark by the answer. @Brian